# unable to upload an image to heroku using the paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am trying to upload an image using my rails app. I can upload an image via localhost. But when i try on heroku I  get a number of errors according to my heroku logs. i get Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError (Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError):

but checked my listings.rb file and it shows the validation code

```
    class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
        if Rails.env.development?
            has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "missing.jpg"
            validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)
        else
        has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "missing.jpg",
                          :storage => :dropbox,
                          :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
                          :path => ":style/id_:filename"
        end 
    end

the rest of the logs is as follows 

    eb.1]: Started POST "/listings" for 92.5.120.49 at 2014-03-11 19:22:08 +0000
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.841367+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/listings" for 92.5.120.49 at 2014-03-11 19:22:08 +0000
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.844182+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"C/PBKkFQp0mnhCF7AKNHB6aI7xuXk6qugZRzJXzay7Y=", "listing"=>{"name"=>"new", "description"=>"test", "price"=>"123", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f962c1a5bc0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140311-2-1kxbxfd>, @original_filename="skillshareimage.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"listing[image]\"; filename=\"skillshareimage.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Listing"}
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.844182+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"C/PBKkFQp0mnhCF7AKNHB6aI7xuXk6qugZRzJXzay7Y=", "listing"=>{"name"=>"new", "description"=>"test", "price"=>"123", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f962c1a5bc0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140311-2-1kxbxfd>, @original_filename="skillshareimage.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"listing[image]\"; filename=\"skillshareimage.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Listing"}
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.843929+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#create as HTML
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.843929+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#create as HTML
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.849897+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.849897+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.847858+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.849897+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:27:in `create'
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.849897+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.847858+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.849897+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.849897+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:27:in `create'
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.849897+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.849897+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.849897+00:00 app[web.1]: Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError (Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError):
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.849897+00:00 app[web.1]: Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError (Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError):
    2014-03-11T19:22:08.854943+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/listings host=ancient-stream-6152.herokuapp.com request_id=b7f4b2fa-178c-4429-93d7-01a3cc2e9e12 fwd="92.5.120.49" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=12797ms status=500 bytes=1543
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.187964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/listings host=ancient-stream-6152.herokuapp.com request_id=c91e444c-f7f1-418f-a8de-963bc67c5c9b fwd="92.5.120.49" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=14ms status=200 bytes=2407
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.175939+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/listings" for 92.5.120.49 at 2014-03-11 19:24:39 +0000
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.175939+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/listings" for 92.5.120.49 at 2014-03-11 19:24:39 +0000
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.177622+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.177622+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#index as HTML
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.182852+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.182852+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.2ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.183742+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.183742+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.1ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.183978+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.183978+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.184228+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:39.184228+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.561315+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/listings/new" for 92.5.120.49 at 2014-03-11 19:24:40 +0000
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.561315+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/listings/new" for 92.5.120.49 at 2014-03-11 19:24:40 +0000
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.561315+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#new as HTML
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.561315+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#new as HTML
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.566669+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/_form.html.erb (4.9ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.567066+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/_form.html.erb (4.9ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.567066+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.4ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.567066+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered listings/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.4ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.567637+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.567637+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.0ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.567880+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.567880+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.567998+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.567998+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    2014-03-11T19:24:40.577742+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/listings/new host=ancient-stream-6152.herokuapp.com request_id=3c8668c4-54ec-4b3f-a0b4-7dbf494af31c fwd="92.5.120.49" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=19ms status=304 bytes=811
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.428834+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/listings" for 92.5.120.49 at 2014-03-11 19:25:04 +0000
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.440967+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/listings" for 92.5.120.49 at 2014-03-11 19:25:04 +0000
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.451100+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#create as HTML
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.457630+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by ListingsController#create as HTML
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.457847+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"C/PBKkFQp0mnhCF7AKNHB6aI7xuXk6qugZRzJXzay7Y=", "listing"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>"", "price"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f962a7e8890 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140311-2-hm3dpx>, @original_filename="newyork.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"listing[image]\"; filename=\"newyork.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Listing"}
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.457847+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"C/PBKkFQp0mnhCF7AKNHB6aI7xuXk6qugZRzJXzay7Y=", "listing"=>{"name"=>"", "description"=>"", "price"=>"", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f962a7e8890 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140311-2-hm3dpx>, @original_filename="newyork.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"listing[image]\"; filename=\"newyork.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Create Listing"}
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.463612+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.463612+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.467213+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.467213+00:00 app[web.1]: Paperc
    lip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError (Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError):
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.467213+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:27:in `create'
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.467213+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.467213+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.467687+00:00 app[web.1]: 
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.467687+00:00 app[web.1]: Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError (Paperclip::Errors::MissingRequiredValidatorError):
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.467687+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:27:in `create'
    2014-03-11T19:25:04.467687+00:00 app[w
```

listings controller.rb

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listings = Listing.all
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /listings/new
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /listings/1
  # DELETE /listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @listing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :description, :price, :image)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either remove the line

```
if Rails.env.development?
```

from your `Listing` model or move the

```
validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png)
```

out of the if statement.

Validation of file type or content type is mandatory in Paperclip now unless you specifically say you don't want to do it.

Refer to https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#security-validations for more information about validations.

Comment: yes working now ,moved the validates_attachement line out of the if statement.  it also fixed another problem becuase it wasn't uploading the images to dropbox via the api - now it is ! thank..Neil